# XSLT Copy-of select with additional (variable) criteria not working

Tags: xslt

With this source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <INVOIC02>
            <E1EDP19>
                <QUALF>003</QUALF>
                <IDTNR>105</IDTNR>
                <KTEXT>TEST-1</KTEXT>
            </E1EDP19>
            <E1EDP19>
                <QUALF>003</QUALF>
                <IDTNR>104</IDTNR>
                <KTEXT>TEST-2</KTEXT>
            </E1EDP19>
        </INVOIC02>
    </multimap:Message1>
    <multimap:Message2>
        <Message2>
            <ZZ1_Result>
                <Material>M1</Material>
                <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
                <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
                <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
            </ZZ1_Result>
            <ZZ1_Result>
                <Material>M2</Material>
                <ProductStandardID>105</ProductStandardID>
                <PurchaseOrder>1B</PurchaseOrder>
                <Supplier>BB</Supplier>
            </ZZ1_Result>
        </Message2>
    </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

I would like to be able to 'find' the ZZ1_Result for each E1EDP19/IDTNR, where ZZ1_Result/ProductStandardID equals E1EDP19/IDTNR.
I can use a fixed value, but am not successful comparing with E1EDP19/IDTNR.

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:soap:messages">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Only match root of IDoc FIDCCP02 -->
    <xsl:template match="document-node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Select all nodes plus attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--At E1EDP19(QUALF=003) segment, field IDTNR, try to find a matching PO item from message 2-->
    <xsl:template match="E1EDP19[QUALF='003']/IDTNR">
        <IDTNR>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </IDTNR>
        <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="//ZZ1_Result[ProductStandardID = '104']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the following result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<Messages xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:soap:messages">
  <Message1>
    <INVOIC02>
      <E1EDP19>
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>105</IDTNR>
        <ZZ1_Result>
          <Material>M1</Material>
          <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
          <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
          <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
        </ZZ1_Result>
        <KTEXT>TEST-1</KTEXT>
      </E1EDP19>
      <E1EDP19>
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>104</IDTNR>
        <ZZ1_Result>
          <Material>M1</Material>
          <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
          <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
          <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
        </ZZ1_Result>
        <KTEXT>TEST-2</KTEXT>
      </E1EDP19>
    </INVOIC02>
  </Message1>
  <Message2>
    <Message2>
      <ZZ1_Result>
        <Material>M1</Material>
        <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
        <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
        <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
      </ZZ1_Result>
      <ZZ1_Result>
        <Material>M2</Material>
        <ProductStandardID>105</ProductStandardID>
        <PurchaseOrder>1B</PurchaseOrder>
        <Supplier>BB</Supplier>
      </ZZ1_Result>
    </Message2>
  </Message2>
</Messages>
```

How can I adjust this line:
<xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="//ZZ1_Result[ProductStandardID = **'104'**]"/>
So instead of the hardcoded '104' it always refers to the "current" E1EDP19[QUALF='003']/IDTNR?

My expected result is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<Messages xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:soap:messages">
  <Message1>
    <INVOIC02>
      <E1EDP19>
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>105</IDTNR>
        <ZZ1_Result>
          <Material>M2</Material>
          <ProductStandardID>105</ProductStandardID>
          <PurchaseOrder>1B</PurchaseOrder>
          <Supplier>BB</Supplier>
        </ZZ1_Result>
        <KTEXT>TEST-1</KTEXT>
      </E1EDP19>
      <E1EDP19>
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>104</IDTNR>
        <ZZ1_Result>
          <Material>M1</Material>
          <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
          <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
          <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
        </ZZ1_Result>
        <KTEXT>TEST-2</KTEXT>
      </E1EDP19>
    </INVOIC02>
  </Message1>
  <Message2>
    <Message2>
      <ZZ1_Result>
        <Material>M1</Material>
        <ProductStandardID>104</ProductStandardID>
        <PurchaseOrder>1A</PurchaseOrder>
        <Supplier>AA</Supplier>
      </ZZ1_Result>
      <ZZ1_Result>
        <Material>M2</Material>
        <ProductStandardID>105</ProductStandardID>
        <PurchaseOrder>1B</PurchaseOrder>
        <Supplier>BB</Supplier>
      </ZZ1_Result>
    </Message2>
  </Message2>
</Messages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct fix is e.g. `<xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="//ZZ1_Result[ProductStandardID = current()]"/>` but these kind of things work better with a key declared e.g. `<xsl:key name="result-by-id" match="ZZ1_Result" use="ProductStandardID"/>` and then `<xsl:copy-of select="key('result-by-id', current())"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:soap:messages">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Remove namespace and take only QName -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--At E1EDP19(QUALF=003) segment, field IDTNR, try to find a matching PO item from message 2-->
    <xsl:template match="E1EDP19">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="QUALF"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="IDTNR"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="IDTNR">
                <xsl:variable name="abc">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="//ZZ1_Result/ProductStandardID">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="text() eq $abc">
                            <xsl:copy-of select=".." copy-namespaces="no"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="KTEXT"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).